# Jersey: saving data in-memory

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am building a simple REST web service using Java and Jersey. I want to store some data in-memory that can be accessed during the time that the server is online. For example:

`http://localhost:8080/register/<someusername>`

would add  to an ArrayList/HashMap/etc that can be accessed by

`http://localhost:8080/list`

which would list the registered users.

How can I accomplish this?

I'm aware that this is not a great way to go about storing data, but for the purposes of my project I'd like it to only be saved while the server is online, and have everything fully reset when it's restarted/stopped/whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this data be all same of all clients, then you can use

@Context
ServletContext servletContext;

Then, put the attribute there and fetch from this attribute on each invocation.

---

If you have some framework, like spring, then you can get/set value with its facilities.

Comment: So, for example if context.getAttribute("users") is null, create a new list of users, add it using context.setAttribute("users",list) and access it in other instances using context.getAttribute("users")?

Comment: ^this seems to be the case. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. If you want more production-like code then you will need sync on some static object or use Lock from concurrency package - on each access to the attribute. You can skip this part however, it will work without errors.

Comment: @Vitaly How do you free this memory ? For every request I am creating new attribute and may not remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make your Jersey class a `@Singleton` and add a `ConcurrentHashMap` field for storing the data.